# Simple Way on Making a Social Media Style Page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, database, web

I'm a beginner with JS (and more experienced with HTML and CSS), and I was wondering if anyone had any simple guides for making a webpage in which users can post content?

Features I wanna include:

1. people can post content. This content has several attributes: a
   title, an item, a quantity of that item, and a location
2. users are able to search content by location and/or item

With as little or as simple JavaScript as possible cuz I'm bad at JavaScript :(

Comment: As it stands, your question is too broad. You would need to give a shot at this first, and come back if you get stuck on a specific problem.

Comment: Maybe one of [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_social_networking_software) will work for you?

Comment: You will need to have some sort of server-side language, whether you stick with JavaScript and write that in Node.js, or use something else like PHP, Rails, etc. You'll also need some sort of database - maybe SQL, but you'll probably a document-based / NoSQL one instead, like MongoDB or Firebase. I'd start off by looking up each of the solutions I mentioned, and figuring out which ones you like more. I'm pretty sure that the basic tutorials for all of them will cover what you want to do; so have fun, go exploring, and come back if you get stuck :)